# shared variable for class instances in Tcl

Tags: oop, static, tcl

In Ruby, one can have a variable shared in for instances of the same class (static). I.e., all see the same value, and can change it. It saves memory, and can have other benefits. This can also be achieved in Perl, C++, etc. How can I achieve the same in Tcl OO, for version 8.6?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since TclOO is intended to be bare bones, it takes a bit of script to achieve the result. The [oo::util](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/ooutil/ooutil.html) package in tcllib supplies the necessary code.

Comment: We might eventually add more class variable and class method support into the core of TclOO. It's not a huge priority for me right now though, especially for class methods (where making self methods on the relevant class object gives 99% of the useful effect).

Answer (score 1):

There's three steps to making a class-scoped variable visible properly to instances.

### Step 1: Set a value in the class:

You don't need to do much with this if you're able to handle a variable starting out unset. Some code can, some can't.

```
oo::class create Example {
    self variable foo
    self method init {} {
        set foo 123
    }
}
Example init
```

### Step 2: Define some methods for instances that will access the variable

Just one for our example. Note that I must *also* say `variable` here; it has a different scope to the `self variable` above. (instance vs class)

```
oo::define Example {
    variable foo
    method bar {} {
        incr foo
        puts "foo is $foo"
    }
}
```

### Step 3: Bind the instance variable to the class variable in the constructor

This is the tricky bit.

```
oo::define Example {
    constructor {} {
        # Get the class's own private object namespace, where it keeps its own variables
        set ns [info object namespace [self class]]
        # Link the instance variable to the class variable; 'my eval' uses right context
        # You can rename the variable here; see 'namespace upvar' docs for details
        my eval [list namespace upvar $ns foo foo]
    }
}
```

With those three, we can make some instances and try them out:

```
set e1 [Example new]
set e2 [Example new]
$e1 bar; # ==> foo is 124
$e1 bar; # ==> foo is 125
$e2 bar; # ==> foo is 126
$e2 bar; # ==> foo is 127
```

Be aware that this works by ***linking*** the variables in the ***instances' namespace*** to the single variable in the ***class's namespace***. This linking is done here with `namespace upvar`, a command you probably haven't used before. It could also have been done with the `upvar` command, though that's less efficient for this sort of thing.

---

## Consolidated script for ease of study

It looks a bit different, but it does the same thing:

```
oo::class create Example {
    self {
        variable foo
        method init {} {
            set foo 123
        }
    }
    variable foo
    constructor {} {
        set ns [info object namespace [self class]]
        my eval [list namespace upvar $ns foo foo]
    }
    method bar {} {
        incr foo
        puts "foo is $foo"
    }
}
Example init
set e1 [Example new]
set e2 [Example new]
$e1 bar; # ==> foo is 124
$e1 bar; # ==> foo is 125
$e2 bar; # ==> foo is 126
$e2 bar; # ==> foo is 127
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) Where is documentation for the behavior of `self { ...}` - all I see is specific subcommands for introspection (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/self.htm), and 2) the code appears to work without the `self {...}` - though obviously the value starts at 1 because there is no `Init` to call.